# How do I properly use types in an F# type provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I working on a type provider for Google BigQuery, which will be my first type provider. I have almost all the puzzle pieces I need to put everything together, but I'm stuck on this last error:

> A reference to the type 'BigQueryProvider.SchemaHandling.Field.Value' in assembly 'BigQueryProvider' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly

Why do I get this error? I have a really hard time understanding what to do since the type is actually in the assembly `BigQueryProvider` and I do load that assembly in my test script.

My plan, which is not working, was the following:

1. Given a query get the metadata for that query
2. Generate a schema for the metadata
3. Create method return types for the schema
4. Create execute method with mapping to the return type following the schema.

First I tried passing in the schema to the method that generates the execute method, but that didn't work either. So now I'm generating the schema twice, when creating the output type and when the execute method is executed runtime. This is where the problems start.

Since this is my first type provider I have probably structured a couple of things wrong, and there is still a lot of things I don't understand, but you have to start somewhere.

The code is here: https://github.com/mastoj/BigQueryProvider/tree/WIP

I have a simple sample scripts that uses the provider here: https://github.com/mastoj/BigQueryProvider/blob/WIP/tests/BigQueryProvider.Tests/QuickTests.fsx

To run anything of this you need the google sdk installed, especially the "bq" (bigquery) command line tooling since I'm using that at the moment to get the metadata for a query.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to create an erasing type provider I think you need to use the other `ProvidedTypeDefinition` constructor (that takes an `Assembly`).

Comment: Could you please try to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` instead of `Assembly.LoadFrom( config.RuntimeAssembly)` like mentioned [in samples](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack/blob/master/tests/BasicErasedProvisionTests.fs#L27) or even better use new [ProvidedTypes API](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack) for erased type providers using `ProvidedTypesContext`

Comment: I did change to `GetExecutingAssembly` and also change to use the other constructor of `ProvidedTypeDefinition` for the row type. The changes make sense, but I now got a new error instead: `The type provider 'BigQueryProvider.BigQueryCommandProvider' reported an error: container type for 'BigQueryProvider.Row' was already set to 'BigQueryProvider.BigQueryCommandProvider,CommandText="SELECT \"tomas\" as name"'` Isn't that a message telling me to not use that constructor? @SergeyTihon